# How can I track my sportmanship progress

Tags: support, sportsmanship-badge

Is there a way that I can track my sportmanship badge progress? It seems that stack exchange data explorer can not help me here as upvoting is anonymous(at least that's what I read in a comment in a query there).

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/102373/how-close-am-i-to-the-sportsmanship-badge